# How do I fold indented function chains in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

For the following code:

```
this.fooService
  .bar$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
  .subscribe(
    (value: ValueType) => {
      // do something
    }
  );
```

Instead of folding it like this:

```
this.fooService
  .bar$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
  .subscribe(
    (value: ValueType) => {...}
  );
```

I want WebStorm to fold it thus:

```
this.fooService ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `editor-fold` and `desc` will be the folded display.

```
this.fooService //<editor-fold desc="...">
  .bar$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
  .subscribe(
    (value: ValueType) => {
      // do something
    }
  );
  //</editor-fold>
```

Ends up doing something like this :

```
this.fooService ...
```

Hope it helps !

Source : [Jetbrains blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/).

Comment: I opted to not use this mainly because I want to avoid adding unnecessary code to the project. This is still a very cool feature.